# I want to access an array of object react native

Tags: arrays, listview, react-native

```js
export default class Send extends Component{
    constructor(props)
    {
    
      super(props);
      const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.state = { 
        userDataSource: ds,
      isLoading: true,
    
      PickerValueHolder : '',
      amount:'',
 RxAmount:'',
 exchange:'',
 input1:'',
 recRate:[{},{},{}]
 
     }
    }
    
    fetchUsers(){
        fetch('https://trs.php?some parameters')
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((response) => {
             console.log(response)
                this.setState({
                    userDataSource: this.state.userDataSource.cloneWithRows(response),
                    
                });
            });
    }
       renderRow(user , sectionId, rowId, highlightRow,key){
           
                return(
                <View style={styles.row}>
                        <Text style={styles.rowText}> Rate {user[0].Rate}</Text>
                    </View>
                
                ); }
```

```html
 <ListView 
    dataSource={this.state.userDataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
/>
```

[i want to access the rate highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoGE6.png)

I am new to react native so i want to access an array of objects and get only one particular value which is highlighted in yellow and i don't know how i can do it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView is [deprecated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html) and it is encouraged that you use [FlatList](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) instead. One reason of which is because of its *"easier to use API"*

Provided that your `userDataSource` object looks like this:

```
[
 {MaxAmt:"value",MinAmt:"value",Rate:"value",RecieverID:"value"},
 {MaxAmt:"value",MinAmt:"value",Rate:"value",RecieverID:"value"},
 {MaxAmt:"value",MinAmt:"value",Rate:"value",RecieverID:"value"}
]
```

Your `renderItem` function (instead of `renderRow`) should look like this:

```
renderItem({item}){
  return(
      <View style={styles.row}>
          <Text style={styles.rowText}> Rate {item.Rate}</Text>
      </View>
  );
}
```

And you can create your list like this:

```
<FlatList
    data=this.state.userDataSource
    renderItem={({item}) => this.renderItem(item)}
/>
```

Comment: i add a snippet code can you show how can i implement your answer

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but it's getting me an error undefined is not an object  "item.Rate"

Comment: To debug what the `item` object is, you can use `alert(item);` inside of you `renderItem` function. This will print out all of your items. (You might have to use `alert(JSON.stringify(item))`). That will tell you what the item object is made up of so you can see why it's `Rate` is undefined.